# How to deal with sql concurrency issues in a website

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I am making a website using asp.net mvc. I have a table that looks like this

```
Create Table Items(
   [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   [Colname] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL
   //OTHER UNIMPORTANT COLS HERE
)

ALTER TABLE Items ADD CONSTRAINT UN_Colanme UNIQUE(Colname)
```

From my website, I frequently try to create new Items, or select items from the database (using entity framework). Here's how it looks in c#

```
var item = db.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Colname == "foo");
if(item == null)
{
   item = new Item("foo");
   db.Items.Add(item);
}

//some stuff with item
db.SaveChanges();
```

Sometimes, 2 requests come in at the same time, both trying to create an item with the same colname. While the unique constraint prevents the database from storing any bad values, trying to save changes throws an exception because the constraint is violated.

Is catching this exception the normal way to handle this? Could I get good performance if instead of the above c# code, I made a stored procedure that locked the table, and then inserted a new row only if it was allowed, and then returned that row? Is that commonly done?

Comment: Guess it depends on just how often this happens... if it's really an exceptional thing happening - then use exceptions to handle this, that's exactly what they're designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are many ways to do this. I would say catching the exception is the least expensive in this scenario. The other way is to raise the transaction isolation level to something much higher like Serializable.

In this scenario though, I would just catch the unique constraint violation and continue on. If we were too think about it in programming terms, we can think about this situation like [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking), in that we check, it's not there, then enter into transaction, see it's there, then we can just discard our value and use the one that is there.

Comment: I tried making a stored proc with transaction isolation level set to serializable earlier. that didn't help because serializable says "Other transactions cannot insert new rows with key values that would fall in the range of keys read by any statements in the current transaction." If you're inserting a new key, you can't possibly have read it, so it won't lock that

Comment: yes, serializable basically locks the entire table just to you, which leads to a lot of contention, but if you do it infrequently, it'd be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thats why many devs use GUIDs or DB allocated Ints as the unique key.   If your externally key is legitimately being allocated and is a logical duplicate, then use the DB duplicate constraint as you have demonstrated or consider using a pessemistic lock .  Sql server has a tool you can use. Search for examples and blogs

- Use Guid key
- Use DB allocated Int as key
- Use Column constraint and catch exception (as you explained)
- Use pessimistic locking, eg SQL inbuilt features

> search web for "SQL server sp_getapplock"   on how to use.

Comment: sorry i forgot to put in the original table definition that the id was a primary key and is generated by the db. colname is not generated by the db and is not the primary key, but it has a unique key on it.